# Automatically print cell values in a new row when cell values change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script for google sheets. I have three cells with data (A1, B1, C1) for which I want new rows to be printed for every change of each of these cells.

After researching a bit online, I've found this script

```
// custom menu function
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Save Data','saveData')
      .addToUi();
}

  function saveData() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    const data1 = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A1').getValue();
    const data2 = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B1').getValue();
    const date = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!C1').getValue();
    sheet.appendRow([data1,data2,date]);
  }
```

That allows me to print data on a buttom click through a custom menu, however instead of manually clicking the button, I would like to have the data printed in new rows automatically whenever the cell value changes. How would I go about achieving this, if even possible?

Comment: There are no triggers that respond to changes made by  formulas or other scripts.

Comment: So are you saying that updates can only be linked to actual user input? Am I understanding you correctly? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Very good.   That is correct, in fact you can  read more about [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedit(e))

Comment: Yep, thanks. I've read through the documentation. After a bit more research, I have set up time-driven triggers instead. They don't achieve quite what I'm looking for i.e. stamping updates based on cell changes, however that do allow me to run an update at pre-defined dates and log them into a different sheet. Updated code in the OP for anyone interested.

Comment: Try: `const [data1, data2, date] = sheet.getRange('A1:C1').getValues().flat()`

Answer (score 0):

So apparently time-stamping and printing changed values does not work if the cells are changed through formula inputs. The only possibility to track upon a cell change is if the user has changed the input manually. I've found this resource to be helpful to set up that sort of automation: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/100381144/new-row-gets-added-to-the-top-of-table-every-time-another-cell-value-changes?hl=en

For my purpose, since the data that is supposed to be printed will be changed through formulas or imports from other sources and specifically not through human input, I've found a workaround to be best, i.e. running changes through time-driven triggers.

An examplary code that achieves this can be found here:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Record value')
      .addItem('Record now','recordValue')
      .addToUi();
}
// Record history from a cell and append to next available row
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Example sheet - automatically updating");
   var logsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Archive");
    var date = new Date();
    var value1 = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
    var value2 = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
    var value3 = sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
    logsheet.appendRow([date, value1, value2, value3]);
}
```

Note that you will have to set up a time-driven trigger as well in order for this to work as desired. For this particular instance, you would need to chose the "RecordValue" function as the one that's executed through the trigger.